# What is this protrusion on the bottom of the sailboat?

Tags: boats, sailing, gear-identification

I recently acquired a sailboat and noticed a small protrusion under the starboard side of the hull in front of the keel. Does anyone know what this is?

The boat is a 1976 hunter 25. I have not put it in the water yet. The head is about directly above in the cabin. The toilet was replaced prior to me acquiring the boat so there is a porta toilet there now, no plumbing.

The hull is fiberglass. The top part looks as if it's wood, and the bottom I can't really tell. There is only one of those protrusions.

Here are some pictures:

Port side view with protruding feature and keel in behind it:
[image: Port side view with protruding feature and Keel in behind it]

Side view of hull with protruding feature:
[image: side view of hull with protruding feature]

View from bottom of hull with protruding feature:
[image: view from bottom of hull with protruding feature]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Depth sounder transducer

This is the transducer for your depth sounder. You should be able to find a cable running from that transducer inside the vessel to the depth sounder display (assuming it's operational).

Given that this is installed directly below the head it would appear that a through-hull that had probably formerly been an intake for the head was repurposed. I would estimate that the installer used that wooden block to position the transducer to point straight down in order to get an accurate depth reading.

Here's a picture of a similar piece of equipment:[image: Cruz-Pro D60 transducer and cable]

Comment: thats it. Its a transducer with wooden fairing block. I looked form the inside and saw the transducer and wiring. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

It used to be the direct discharge for the head into the water.  Here is a [blog about a boat similar to yours, asking if it is illegal](https://forums.sailboatowners.com/index.php?threads/direct-discharge-head-illegal.185226/)

It was not unusual in the era of your boats manufacture to discharge raw sewage into the water.

Legality varies, but currently it is NOT a popular choice.

Adding a holding tank to old boats is difficult, a common solution is to swap in a porta toilet (toilet and holding tank combined).

If you are doing significant repairs, you may want to remove 'protrusion' and re-fiberglass to make that area smooth.

Comment: Given the position, this was more likely an intake than discharge, but sewage discharge regulations aren't really relevant to the question at hand.

Comment: @Tuorg I removed the regulations from my answer.  I like your answer.

Comment: thanks. Don't get me started on overboard discharge regulations! ;)